# Does akka support higher-order actors?

Tags: scala, akka, actor

I would like to pass a serialized Actor together with its state to another Actor (so it can be migrated across the network). Is there any API for that or should one be implemented from scratch?

Comment: The short answer is no, but the longer answer is use remoting per @cmbaxter.  You can't actually send an actor that is already created but you can create a new actor remotely with all its parameters (state).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that this type of feature is supported by Remoting in Akka.  Check out this link, specifically the section on Programmatic Remote Deployments and see if that's what you are looking for:

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.1.2/java/remoting.html

Also, `ActorRefs` are serializable, so you can certainly pass an `ActorRef` to another actor on a remote node and then send a message back to the ref you supplied, resulting in the message traveling back to the starting node.

One more thing to think of.  You can not actually pass an `Actor` instance to another actor, all you can actually pass is the `ActorRef`, which is a lightweight handle for calling back to the `Actor` instance that the ref represents.  If you truly want to migrate an actor instance and it's state to another node, then read more into the Programmatic Remote Deployment feature.  If you just want to communicate back and forth between two actor instances running in separate nodes, then either use `ask (?)` to get request/response behavior (using the `sender` var in the receiving actor to send back to the calling actor, or pass the sending `ActorRef` (via `context.self`) along via `tell (!)` and then use that ref in the receiving actor to send a message back.